# UITextField not working inside a UITabBarController with IOS5

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitextfield

Are there any restrictions on a `UITextField` when placed inside a tabview which not the main interface. In other words

Working fine scenario
1. A tab based application, with one of the view having a `UITextField`.
2. The tabview is the main interface for the application.

This works fine without any glitches

Not-working so fine scenario.
1. A tab based application, but the tab view is not the mainview.
2. There is another view `MainWindow.xib` with some intro animation, which then calls and shows the tabview.
3. `UITextfield` in such tabviews does'nt seem to work - especially in IOS5. Both methods work fine till IOS 4.3
4. The textfield is visible, but tapping it does not show any keyboard, if i call `becomeFirstResponder` via code, the keyboard is shown but is not responsive.

Any suggestions

The code is pretty standard

in the `AppDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    tabViewController = [[tabView alloc] initWithNibName:@"tabView" bundle:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:tabViewController.view];     
     //self.window.rootViewController=tabViewController
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    
    return YES;    
}
```

tabViewController has a `ProfileViewController` with a simple textfield.

The textfield works fine if i do this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

tabViewController = [[tabView alloc] initWithNibName:@"tabView" bundle:nil];
profileView=[[Profile alloc] initWithNibName:@"Profile" bundle:nil];
//calling the view directly without using a tab view
[self.window addSubview:profileView.view];     
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    
return YES;
```

}

Is there something else that needs to be done for IOS5 when the tab view is not the main interface? I have been cracking my head at this for a few days, all my apps with a `UITextfield`  inside a tabview are not usable in ios5. Any help is highly appreciated

Edit: Uploaded the project file http://www.mediafire.com/?xjuc4udlph78saj - XCode 4.2 on Lion

It is a simple project with two options, Creating a tabbarcontroller from the delegate itself, and i also have a view(tabView) with a tabbarcontroller. There are 2 views for the tabbar `FirstViewController` & `SecondViewController`. 
In the `AppDelegate.m` if using method 1(create `UITabBarController` inside `AppDelegate`, all is well). If i choose to add a subview of tabView, the uitextfield does not work.
I have not really handled the releasing of objects, since this is test project and it is only for proof of concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching, fiddling and experimenting. I have found out the solution.

This seems to happen when there are more than one `UIWindow` in the application.
In my case, i was diong this

- `AppDelegate` starts off with its own `UIWindow`  Once i have played some
  startup animations, i try to display another view with a
  tabbarcontroller, and ofcoures a window to hold the `UITabBarController`

  The second window (even after setting it to `makeKeyAndVisible`) seems
  to be blocking keyboard events fore `UITextField` inside the
  `UITabBarController`.

The following has worked for me:
Rather than having the second view with its own window, i had it with a `UITabBarController`, and a `UIView`/`UIWindow`(this is for the sake of having a default view for the nib file). And when i needed to show the tabbarview i have used this

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:TabBar]
```

I am not sure of a better way, but that have worked for me. In short, i have found that having another `UIWindow` inside the app causes issues with `becomeFirstResponder`.